# Getting all pending requests one to many mappings

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-5.x

I have two tables (**requests** and **requests_details**) like as shown below. **requests** table have request_id and request name and **requests_details** have the details whether the request is in pending, approved or rejected. I have implemented the below two tables in one to many mapping using Spring JPA. In **requests_details** table if there is second entry apart from PENDING status for a request then it means from the status we can know if the request is approved or a rejected one

Now I have a requirement to get all the pending and approval requests separately

I have wrote the hql query like as shown below

### For getting all the pending requests

```
SELECT request.name, details.* 
FROM requests request JOIN request_details details ON request.request_id=details.request_id 
WHERE 
details.status = "PENDING" AND 
details.status !="APPROVED" OR details.status !="REJECTED"
```

but for the above query it is returning all the requests

### For getting all the approved requests

```
SELECT request.name, details.* 
FROM requests request JOIN request_details details ON request.request_id=details.request_id 
WHERE 
details.status = "PENDING" AND 
details.status ="APPROVED"
```

but for the above query it is not returning any requests

[image]

### My expected result is as give below

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to get, but `details.status = "PENDING" AND 
details.status ="APPROVED"` is obviously not possible to satisfy and `details.status = "PENDING" AND 
details.status !="APPROVED" OR details.status !="REJECTED"` is equivalent to `(details.status = "PENDING" AND 
details.status !="APPROVED") OR details.status !="REJECTED"` is equivalent to `details.status = "PENDING" OR details.status !="REJECTED"` is equivalent to `details.status !="REJECTED"` which is satisfied by all rows in the given example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening in the first query is that you are stating that the status should be "PENDING" and **not** "APPROVED" (this covers "REJECTED") or not "REJECTED" (this covers all other cases) that is why you get everything.

If you are trying to get all "PENDING" then just simply

```
SELECT
  request.id,
  details.*
FROM requests request
  JOIN request_details details ON request.request_id = details.request_id
WHERE details.status = "PENDING"
AND (SELECT count(*) FROM requests_details
     WHERE requests_details.request_id = request.request_id) = 1
```

The subquery makes sure there is only one entry for the request meaning it is only "PENDING" and has not be approved or rejected.

---

In the second case you are getting nothing back because you are stating that the status should be "PENDING" **and** "APPROVED" at the same time and that will always be false.

If you want to get entries that are both "PENDING" and "APPROVED" then you can do something like this

```
SELECT
  request.request_id,
  details.*
FROM requests request
  JOIN requests_details details ON request.request_id = details.request_id
WHERE details.status = 'PENDING'
  AND (SELECT count(*) FROM requests_details
         WHERE requests_details.request_id = request.request_id
           AND requests_details.status = 'APPROVED'
      ) = 1
```

What happens is that you find all "PENDING" requests and then make sure those are **also** "APPROVED". This is done with the subquery. There you only need to know that the record with the right id and the "APPROVED" status exists, that is why you would use the count, the data you already have from the previous part.

---

NOTE: It would be a good idea to update the status of requests from "PENDING" to "APPROVED" or "REJECTED" rather than inserting a new record. This would be safer and queries would be more simple and faster (you wouldn't need the subquery). It would also avoid possible bugs where requests end up having multiple conflicting statuses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually your PENDING query returns me the full requests which includes the approved one as well. I have updated my question with the expected result. Can you please take a look

Comment: @AlexMan SO you mean it should only be "PENDING" and nothing else right? I misunderstood that.

Comment: @AlexMan I updated the answer, hope it is what you are looking for. Don't forget to test it and maybe you have to tweek it a bit, I am after all writing this without and IDE and never ran it. Also if it helped you don't forget to upvote and accept it :)